# Flyway scripts migration execution order while running test cases Junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, flyway, spring-boot-test

In our Spring boot Java project we are having flyway migration scripts. Below is our project structure,

```
Project
 |
 |    
 +-- src
 |  |  
 |  +-- resources
        |
        +-- db.migration
            |
            +--V1_0_db_script.sql (scheme_one)
 +-- test
 |  |  
 |  +-- resources
 |      |
 |      +-- db
        |    |
        |    +-- data-test
        |    |           |
        |    |       +--V1_0_test_db_script.sql (scheme_one)
        |    +-- data-sql
        |    |           |
        |    |           +--V1_0_sql_db_script.sql (scheme_second)
        |    |
        +-- application-test.yml
```

Now, here is my application-test.yml structure.

```
Flyway :
    enabled: true
    schemas: scheme_one
    locations: 
     - classpath: /db/data-sql
     - classpath: /db/migration
     - classpath: /db/data-test
```

Now, what is needed here is that while running test cases, it should execute `data-sql` directory first it means `V1_0_sql_db_script.sql` should execute first then `db.migration` and then `data-test` directory. But its not executing in the order which defined in location (My assumption is from top to bottom, even I tried bottom to top).

Now what's happening, it always first executing `db.migration` which is located under main src package. But I want to execute `data-sql` directory scripts first anyhow while test cases are started to run as there are some queries which is needed for other scripts. One more thing, there are actually two different schemes used. I have defined in brackets.

Kindly suggest if flyway have any property to define order or any other feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Flyway orders migrations by version number in the file name from the locations you define. Your example has every script at V1_0. Have you tried changing the versions to control the order?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware about the versioning. But all db script files are on different folder (directory).

Comment: Right, but I believe that flyway doesn't order by directories, but rather discovers all files within the locations and orders by this. The naming of your scripts doesn't fully comply with the convention defined by flyway. See flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations.html#naming-1 (Double underscore to separate version and description) I recommend trying to version the scripts in numerical order.

Comment: Can you implement your requirements with the `init-sqls` property @ODDminus1

Comment: @ODDminus1 I tried to update the versions of the db script. But it looks like flyway always first executing main src directory which is db.migrate and not taking first priority to test directory which is test/resources/db/data-sql. My need to execute test db scripts first instead of main src.